# How can I assist in testing RingCT on the Monero testnet?

Tags: ringct, testnet

I hear that RingCT is currently fully deployed on the Monero testnet, and that we can assist with stress testing the protocol by creating a testnet account ourselves. I created my own testnet wallet and had one of the Monero developers send me some testnet XMR. How can I help in testing RingCT on testnet? Do they simply want me to send various amounts of XMR to various developers on the testnet?

Here are the testnet XMR addresses I've found for various devs (hat-tip MoneroWorld):

Gingeropolous: 9zKiBBQ6E61LxDuNp3abSDZhE7LEargDMCTYJkj2coqfdFYWXXdxNLRX2JRKhVkHP2Vgvg4MxitT3VMSMKRzbxVs8fSLBD5

Moneromoooo: 9yvGzysbcaWPHNjzkdKTMy5E7uvf85eNtZmuDQ3FLJrq3TeMy9cEaEi5CK7FqXNboWKHBvLGAxHFB5gq8KpSxmgJPah9MJc

iDunk: 9tLGyK277MnYrDc7Vzi6TB1pJvstFoviziFwsqQNFbwA9rvg5RxYVYjEezFKDjvDHgAzTELJhJHVx6JAaWZKeVqSUZkXeKk

hyc: 9xSS2SPW21rQzSzSVLue64MfQnAu3rynRaRBgiaLNPAC1pVnjEXcQ6K5BCJuDz58cHZMtyqJg4iJYZ15NJsdFiG28wjQJ8M

jr2016x30: 9yKAHBHKdyDdANzp3quDK5Kh7aMczoJiDAsgi7FGreA1QGwJ2FN6QEuZZi99s9NQMjaJtbfWKGfnz9pno7Z1LZAgNQeNA1n

Am I missing any?

Comment: Try `./monerod --help`. That will bring up some possible flags, including how to run the daemon on testnet. (But I never tried it, so I don't really know what I am talking about.) From reading it, it seems that just using the flag `--testnet` should do the trick. I imagine you would be downloading the testnet blockchain after that for a while though.

Comment: I know how to use the --testnet flag, etc. What I'm asking is the specific actions I can take to assist in testing RingCT, eg: spamming various transactions to various devs or whatnot.

Comment: Okay, I just got my testnet node setup. If someone can, please send me some coins 9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8jxNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSguEMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p

Comment: Gotchu man! 300 textnetXMR headed your way tx: 42fdaf8ca6bf188cad0a22a35d02f83acb3f43532e9799be6a2ee65f6b357623

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Is there a blockchain explorer for testnet? I really wanted to see how Confidential Transactions look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can help by performing the most unlikely actions that should still work, keeping track of what you do, and reporting what doesn't work.

Sending transactions to other addresses is the obvious case, which has been well tested already. Things worth testing now are features that were added recently to the git repository, such as cold wallet signing.

You can also test restoring a wallet through various means (from seed, from keys, etc), and checking ringct transactions are still recognized. You can check all transfer commands: transfer, sweep_unmixable, sweep_all. You can check that you can still prove a payment using get_tx_key/check_tx_key. Basically, go through everything, especially the most obscure, since that's what is more likely to have been overlooked.

If anything does not work, please file a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues, detailing what you tried, what the results were, and what you expected would happen instead.

Thanks for testing!