# Problem transfering to Monero address copied from SE comment using monero-wallet-cli. `Error: wrong address`

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, testnet

I was trying to send some testnet coins to myself to an old address that I posted in a comment in this [post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/how-can-i-assist-in-testing-ringct-on-the-monero-testnet#comment1012_1889). You can see that xmr_eric was successful in sending me some coins at the time. So today I tried to copy the address from that comment I made into monero-wallet-cli and do

`transfer 9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8j‌​xNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSgu‌​EMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p 1`,

but then I get:

`Error: wrong address: 9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8j‌​xNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSgu‌​EMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p`...

I assume it is something that happens when copying from that particular SE comment. I tried from two different computers and the two wallets gave the same error. Actually, if I run exactly the same command, copying the address from inside the wallet itself:

`transfer 9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8j‌​xNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSgu‌​EMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p 1`

I get the normal response:

`transfer 9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8jxNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSguEMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p 1
The transaction fee is 0.026000000000.
Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No)n`

I compared the two strings in a text editor, and they are visibly identical... And, sure enough, if I just type the address, character by character, then it works fine. Do you know what this could be?

Answer (score 4):

In the first two cases you have "\n" in the address.

`9z1N6pssDU3hvq9X6iqxk2g2e4tfc2WqfiMcKLR2dE8mZVjGN4yCKBD4QE8j‌<\n>​
xNMMCabNQNzDKLUnZSgu‌​EMMr4YPSBcMuJ8p`

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't show when I copy it to my text editor... but if you can see that, I bet that is the reason.